# XAML - Binding to a Brush using the Element

Tags: wpf, xaml, ivalueconverter

I want to set the `Background Brush` for a Window using **Binding**. The problem is that I need to access a `Resource` to do that which means the `Background` property has to be set after the `Resources`.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../../Resources/Global.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.Style>
    <StaticResource ResourceKey="Style.Dialog" />
</Window.Style>
<Window.Background>
    <Binding Source="Severity" Converter="{StaticResource Converter.SeverityTypeToColor}" />
</Window.Background>
```

The above code doesn't work and I can't find anything online.

How do I bind the `Background` after the `Resources`?

Comment: Ok so it turns out that all this was because the converter was getting "Severity" passed in instead of the value of the Severity property. I changed the attribute from Source to Path and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use [DynamicResource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms748942%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

To set your Window background, reference the ColorBrush with a DynamicResource binding. Ran a quick test on the following, worked fine. Ensure that the binding to the background is actually a ColorBrush and not a Color.

```
<Window 
        .... skipping namespace and other references ...

     Title="MainWindow" 
     Background="{DynamicResource MyBackgroundBrush}" >

    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <!-- rest of the xaml -->
</Window>
```

Comment: This is not answering my problem. I have a Binding not a Resource that I need to reference to get the Background (and you can't DynamicResource a Converter).

Answer (score 0):

OK so it turns out that all this was because the converter was getting `"Severity"` passed in instead of the value of the `Severity` property. I changed the attribute from `Source` to `Path` and it worked.

e.g.

```
<Binding Path="Severity" Converter="{StaticResource Converter.SeverityTypeToColor}" />
```